# Is it possible run multiple setup scripts of subdirectories on docker container startup

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I would like to run an oracle docker container using docker-compose. In my docker-compose.yml file i mount the docker volume as
`volumes: - /host/folder:/opt/oracle/scripts/setup`

Actually the /host/folder has multiple subdirectories containing some setup scripts which i want them to be executed when i do docker-compose up. Would runScripts.sh in container consider the subdirectories too ?

Comment: I does if the script is written to do that. For help writing scripts, unix.SE may be a better place. This is a shell scripting question, not a docker question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `docker-compose` does not consider your subdirectories for that.

You can run a specific bash script according to your requirements in which you can execute the specific scripts.

Your `docker-compose.yml` will look like following:

```
version: "3"

services:
  setup:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    volumes:
      - ./startup-script.sh:/root/startup-script.sh
      - /host/folder:/opt/oracle/scripts/setup
    entrypoint: "/root/startup-script.sh"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

And `startup-script.sh` will look like following:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash /directory1/script.sh
bash /directory2/script.sh
bash /directory3/script.sh
bash /directory4/script.sh

/bin/bash
exec "$@"
```

So, when docker container gets up, `startup-script.sh` will be executed and it will then execute all of your other required scripts.

**Note:** If your container is not of `ubuntu` image and supports `sh` instead of `bash`, then you can replace `/bin/bash` with `bin/sh` within your `docker-compose.yml` and `startup-script.sh`